# PHP Get Variable From Case Switch

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement

I am using a switch function to change variables on my page depending on the variable set in the URL (http://localhost/design/?state=AL).

I keep getting an error of:  Notice: Undefined variable: topBeacon in C:\wamp\www\design\includes\strobeLaws.php on line 84

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['state']))
{
    $term = strtolower($_GET['state']);
    switch($term)
    {
        case 'SL':
            echo "<td>Please select a state.</td>";
            break;
        case 'AL':
            $topBeacon = 'Amber';
            $forwardBeacon = 'Amber';
            $rearBeacon = 'Amber';
            break;          
    }
}
?>
```

And the section of HTML containing where the variable should echo:

```
<tr>
<td>Top Beacon:</td>
<td><?php echo $topBeacon; ?></td> <!--Line 84 From Error -->
</tr>
```

I think I did everything correctly, but I am not understanding why I am getting an error when my variable is set.

Comment: $topBeacon will only be DEFINED IF the switch lands on 'AL'. if it lands on anything else, $topBeacon will remain undefined.

Comment: I'm aware of how that works. I have already mentioned that even with 'AL' set it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rewriting the code over and over I figured it out. I started out with a generic example to work off of. I missed one important detail and so did everyone that answered so I am posting this as an answer for future reference.

I stated that my URL looked like this: http://localhost/design/?state=AL

I forgot that this line existed: $term = strtolower($_GET['state']);

And an example of one of my cases:

```
         case 'AL':
            $topBeacon = 'Amber';
            $forwardBeacon = 'Amber';
            $rearBeacon = 'Amber';
            break;
```

My switch case function was waiting for the URL to land on capital letters while the $term was getting turned into lower case letters.

This is the full updated code so far(working that is, not including all 50 states):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['state']))
{
    $term = strtoupper($_GET['state']);
    switch($term)
    {
         default:
            $topBeacon = 'Select A State';
            $forwardBeacon = 'Select A State';
            $rearBeacon = 'Select A State';
        case 'SL':
            $topBeacon = 'Select A State';
            $forwardBeacon = 'Select A State';
            $rearBeacon = 'Select A State';
            break;
        case 'AL':
            $topBeacon = 'Amber';
            $forwardBeacon = 'Amber';
            $rearBeacon = 'Amber';
            break;       
    }
}
?>
 <table style="width:400px" id="strobeLawsTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Top Beacon:</td>
    <td><?php echo isset($topBeacon) ? $topBeacon : ''; ?></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Forward Facing:</td>
    <td><?php echo isset($forwardBeacon) ? $forwardBeacon : ''; ?></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rear Facing:</td>
    <td><?php echo isset($rearBeacon) ? $rearBeacon : ''; ?></td>       
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the code path for the case when `$term` equals `'SL'`, `$topBeacon` is not set and therefore leads to the undefined error.

If you want to resolve the error, and I recommend doing so, you could add logic to conditionally display these variables.

For example:

```
<tr>
<td>Top Beacon:</td>
<td><?php echo isset($topBeacon) ? $topBeacon : ''; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Another alternative would be to default `$topBeacon` (and other variables):

```
$topBeacon = '';
// default additional variables

$term = strtolower($_GET['state']);
switch($term)
{
   // ...
```

Comment: Thing is my url is set to $state=AL right now which has the variable set in the switch statements. Even when I added your isset solution nothing happens when i switch the URL from SL to AL.

Comment: Seems like something else is wrong in your code. For example, you are testing lower case vs. upper case.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm not noticing though. It appears correct, but it's not registering the fact that the variable is set for some reason. Has to be something small that I am overlooking.